# Is the prohibition to praise idolators inclusive of all gentiles?

Tags: halacha, avodah-zarah

Let say someone has gentile students who are doing well, and they are not idolators. Is it permissible to praise and recognize their good deeds?

Comment: In the Shulchan Aruch, it's commentaries, Chochmas Adam and Aruch HaShulchan I didn't see any distinctions. Doesn't mean there are none...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this shiur](https://www.torahanytime.com/#/lectures?v=97153) by Rabbi Doniel Kleinman there are two heterim to this issur: 1)If praising the non-Jew benefits the Jew. So if one has gentile students, it his professional duty to encourage them, and it should be permitted. 2)He quotes Rav Shmuel Kamenetsky (about 47 minutes in) as saying the issur is only to praise a non-Jew excessively, but a simple remark or comment is ok.

Answer (score -4):

I deleted this answer of mine, but the more I think about it the more I think it is correct.  What is accomplished by saying “Blessed be He who has created such in His universe!” instead of directly praising the idolater?  It sounds like playing word games to me.

Who are these idolaters to be praised?  A beautiful person?  A great doctor?  A hero who risked his life to save lots of children?  A genius of an inventor?  If you just say “Blessed be He who has created such in His universe!”, people will ask you why you said that.  Are you going to answer "I can't tell you because I can't praise an idolater"?

Kiddushin 40a says:  "He who is evil to Heaven but not evil to man, he is a wicked man who is not evil."

==============

It is not prohibited to praise idolaters.  The Talmud says:

> Rav said: One is forbidden to say, “How beautiful is this idolatress!”
> The following objection was raised: Once, Rabbi Shim’on ben Gamliel, while standing on a step on the Temple Mount, saw a certain idolatress who was exceedingly beautiful, and exclaimed: “How great are Your works, O Lord!” [Ps. 104:24]
> Likewise, when Rabbi Akiva saw the wife of the wicked Tyrannus Rufus, [Tineius Rufus, Governor of Judea, 1st century CE] he spat, then laughed, and then wept.  'Spat,' because she originated only from a putrid drop; [Avot 3:1] 'laughed,' because he foresaw that she would convert to Judaism and he would marry her; 'wept', [to think] that such beauty should [ultimately] decay in the dust.
> What then about Rav's ruling [that one must not admire the beauty of idolaters? Rav might say that] each of these rabbis merely gave praise [to God for the beauty He brought into being].  For a Master has said: One who sees beautiful creatures should say: “Blessed be He who has created such in His universe.” [Ber. 58b]
> [Avodah Zarah 20a]

Comment: Notice in the above case that it begins by talking about praising the creator, not the akum themselves.

Comment: See more here: https://www.halachipedia.com/index.php?title=Complimenting_Non-Jews

Comment: What you quote explicitly forbids praising idolators...

Comment: Maurice you can call it word-games all day but it's still explicitly the halacha in the talmud. Sometimes subtle differences matter in Law.

Comment: By rough analogy there are volumes written just about how to indirectly ask a gentile to light a fire on the Sabbath

Comment: Are there also volumes about how to answer:  "Why did you make that blessing"?